# How do I set up my covariates?

Tags: mixed-model, anova, covariance

I am trying to design a fairly basic lme in Matlab for an experiment. I have been trying to wrap my head around covariates design and my advisor has been less than helpful.

I have various metric (dependent variables) that I wanted to look for changes in 4 different trials that were all run by 16 participants. I created this lme for all dependent variables I wanted to look at as:
'DEP ~ TRIAL+(1|PARTICIPANT)+(1|SEX)'

However, for a a subset of the the dependent variables I am looking at, through using different groupings in data, I found massive differences between SEX. I would like to dive deeper into this effect and see if it is truly a SEX based dependency or on something else like WEIGHT (I have this data).

I set up another lme as such to show the sharp differences between SEX:

[image: lme SEX results]

This shows drastically different results for Men and Women but I have a suspicion it has more to do with WEIGHT than SEX. I can build another model using WEIGHT where SEX is, but how do I know it is a better model? Should I be using multiple covariates? Any help would be appreciated as I am far from a master at lmes. Thanks!

Comment: You can compare model fit by looking at the AIC (Akaike's Information Criterion, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion). The smaller AIC, the better.